# Error when trying to access index.php in a mediawiki server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, mediawiki

I'm running an apache server and a mysql db with docker composer. I do have connection with the server but i keep getting this error when i try to access index.php (so i can configure my MediaWiki page):

> *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCode() on null in /var/www/html/includes/user/User.php on line 1578*

I've checked User.php but everything seems fine.

[error i get in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veRfT.png)

```
    $defOpt = $wgDefaultUserOptions;
    // Default language setting
    $defOptLang = $wgContLang->getCode();
    $defOpt['language'] = $defOptLang;
    foreach ( LanguageConverter::$languagesWithVariants as $langCode ) {
        $defOpt[$langCode == $wgContLang->getCode() ? 'variant' : "variant-$langCode"] = $langCode;
    }
```

Someone can give me a hand here? Thanks

Comment: you have to show the `User.php` code

Comment: it's too long, but I can show you the part where the error is:

Comment: Something is causing an error before language handling has been set up, resulting in another error when the error formatter tries to localize the error message. This seems like a bug in MediaWiki (should check whether `$wgContLang` is available first), sadly it also masks the real error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue installing an clean version of apache and mediawiki (same version as the old) and later exporting the old apache2_conf/ directory to the new /etc/apache2/ directory, after this, I migrated the MySQL DB.